# Create Venn Diagram from two DF

Tags: r, dataframe, venn-diagram

I'm trying to create a Venn diagram of two data frames, but am only able receive incorrect results. An example of the data sets of the same structure:

| Chemical | ChemID |
| --- | --- |
| Oxidopamine | D016627 |
| Melatonin | D016627 |

I've only received incorrect results from the following:

```
VennDiagram::venn.diagram(
  x = list(Lewy,  Park),
  category.names = c("ChemID, ChemID"),
  filename ="venndiagramm.png",
  output=TRUE)
```

Ideally, I would like to export an image of number of overlapping chemicals between the two sets.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! As far as I guess your data structure (two dataframes `Lewy` and `Park`, each with the column `ChemID`), try the following:

```
VennDiagram::venn.diagram(
  x = list(Lewy$ChemID, Park$ChemID),  # expects vectors, not dataframes
  # category.names = c("ChemID, ChemID"), # see if these are rather to construct nice labels
  filename ="venndiagramm.png",
  output=TRUE)
```

You may increase the chance of a useful answer by providing minimal working data samples by `dput()`. Of course you can use simulated data. Try to explain what exactly did not work.

See also `? venn.diagram`